# Filter Rows Based on String AC27 and AC28

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

| im_id | sub_status | status_date | Flag_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | PD01 | 01-FEB-2023 |  |
| 12345 | PD02 | 02-FEB-2023 |  |
| 12345 | PD81 | 02-FEB-2023 |  |
| 12345 | PD63 | 02-FEB-2023 |  |
| 12345 | AC27 | 02-FEB-2023 |  |
| 12345 | AC27 | 03-FEB-2023 | Cancel Not Available |
| 12345 | AC28 | 03-FEB-2023 | Cancel Not Available |
| 12345 | AC01 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 22233 | PD01 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 22233 | AC27 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 22233 | S02 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 22233 | DN99 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 22233 | PD01 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 22233 | AC27 | 05-FEB-2023 | No Infusion Only |
| 22233 | AC28 | 05-FEB-2023 | No Infusion Only |
| 22233 | AC29 | 06-FEB-2023 | No Infusion Only |
| 22233 | AC02 | 05-FEB-2023 |  |
| 55522 | AC27 | 06-FEB-2023 | Cancel Not Available |
| 55522 | AC28 | 04-FEB-2023 | Cancel Not Available |
| 55522 | AC28 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 55522 | AC29 | 04-FEB-2023 |  |
| 55522 | AC27 | 05-FEB-2023 |  |
| 77732 | AC27 | 05-FEB-2023 | Cancel Not Available |
| 77732 | AC28 | 06-FEB-2023 | Cancel Not Available |
| 77732 | AC01 | 05-FEB-2023 |  |
| 77732 | PD02 | 06-FEB-2023 |  |

In above data frame (Table Name-DF) "im_id", "sub_status" and "status_date" are 3 input columns.
The expected result will be shown in "Flag Status" column.

**Here I want 2 results mentioned as below**

**1st Scenario-**

Do Filter only those records for where ims_id should match with sub_status **"AC27"** and **"AC28"** and Not Matched with **"CC38"**. In this, code should filter only those records for **each ims_id** where **"AC28" comes after "AC27"** and expected string should be visible Infront of both **AC27** and **"AC@*"** as **"Cancel Not Available"**

The Output mentioned in above table, in that you can see "AC28" comes after "AC27" and expected string **"Cancel Not Available"** exist Infront of "AC27 and AC28".

**2nd Scenario-**

Do Filter only those records for where ims_id should align with sub_status **"AC27"**, **"AC28"**, **"AC29"** and Not Matched with **"AC01"**. In this, code should filter only those records for **each ims_id** where **"AC28" comes after "AC27"** and **"AC29"** comes after **"AC28"**. expected string should be visible Infront of **AC27, AC28 and AC29** as **"No Infusion Only"**

The Output mentioned in above table, in that you can see "AC28" comes after "AC27" and "AC29" comes after "AC28" and expected string **"No Infusion Only"** exist Infront of "AC27, AC28 and AC29".

**Note: Bothe Scenarios should not mix the results. Earlier I tried filter, subset method but it will not give expected result.**

I Tried Below Code for **1st Scenario** But while filtering it's selecting all records.

```
DF$Flag_Status <- ifelse(DF$sub_status %in% c("AC27", "AC28") & 
                         DF$sub_status != "CC38", "Cancelled_Not_Available", DF$Flag_Status)
```

I Tried Below Code for **2nd Scenario** But while filtering it's selecting all records.

```
DF$Flag_Status <- ifelse(DF$sub_status %in% c("AC27", "AC28", "AC29") & 
                         DF$sub_status != "AC01", "No Infusion Only", DF$Flag_Status)
```

**But in expected results after executing second chunk the earlier results overridden because AC27 and AC28 was included in Scenario 1st.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For filtering data i used few line that i mentioned above. If you need code to reproduce data frame then i will do that ?

Comment: hi @MaheshKulkarni can you write out the rules as pseudocode? Thanks